# JWT refresh tokens not required for re-authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token, jwt

Till now i am using short-lived token and refresh token for API auth. I am using refresh token only for getting user-id to query database to check latest permissions and active/blocked status of user. Now i am thinking that why should not i extract this user-id from short-liven token itself. The following function is used to decode JWT, in this expiration is verified after signature verification. So if i get 'expiration' error it means then token signature is good and token is un-tempered. Now i can extract middle(yyy out of xxx.yyy.zzz) base64 encoded data from expired JWT to get user-id. So i don't seeing worth using refresh token. Further longer time access can also be defined in token itself with just custom timestamp so that i have both time limits in one token for example 5 minutes and 90 days. What are your thoughts?

```
public static function decode($jwt, $key, array $allowed_algs = array())
    {
        $timestamp = is_null(static::$timestamp) ? time() : static::$timestamp;

        if (empty($key)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Key may not be empty');
        }
        $tks = explode('.', $jwt);
        if (count($tks) != 3) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Wrong number of segments');
        }
        list($headb64, $bodyb64, $cryptob64) = $tks;
        if (null === ($header = static::jsonDecode(static::urlsafeB64Decode($headb64)))) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid header encoding');
        }
        if (null === $payload = static::jsonDecode(static::urlsafeB64Decode($bodyb64))) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid claims encoding');
        }
        if (false === ($sig = static::urlsafeB64Decode($cryptob64))) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid signature encoding');
        }
        if (empty($header->alg)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Empty algorithm');
        }
        if (empty(static::$supported_algs[$header->alg])) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Algorithm not supported');
        }
        if (!in_array($header->alg, $allowed_algs)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Algorithm not allowed');
        }
        if (is_array($key) || $key instanceof \ArrayAccess) {
            if (isset($header->kid)) {
                if (!isset($key[$header->kid])) {
                    throw new UnexpectedValueException('"kid" invalid, unable to lookup correct key');
                }
                $key = $key[$header->kid];
            } else {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException('"kid" empty, unable to lookup correct key');
            }
        }

        // Check the signature
        if (!static::verify("$headb64.$bodyb64", $sig, $key, $header->alg)) {
            throw new SignatureInvalidException('Signature verification failed');
        }

        // Check the nbf if it is defined. This is the time that the
        // token can actually be used. If it's not yet that time, abort.
        if (isset($payload->nbf) && $payload->nbf > ($timestamp + static::$leeway)) {
            throw new BeforeValidException(
                'Cannot handle token prior to ' . date(DateTime::ISO8601, $payload->nbf)
            );
        }

        // Check that this token has been created before 'now'. This prevents
        // using tokens that have been created for later use (and haven't
        // correctly used the nbf claim).
        if (isset($payload->iat) && $payload->iat > ($timestamp + static::$leeway)) {
            throw new BeforeValidException(
                'Cannot handle token prior to ' . date(DateTime::ISO8601, $payload->iat)
            );
        }

        // Check if this token has expired.
        if (isset($payload->exp) && ($timestamp - static::$leeway) >= $payload->exp) {
            throw new ExpiredException('Expired token');
        }

        return $payload;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Your plan breaks the common practice. It is also against the OAuth standard. New developer will think it is a bug. Your company might hire security auditor and that person will test access with expired token. This will be reported as something you have to fix.

Comment: Okay, but do you see any vulnerability ? I want to drop refresh token to save bandwidth.

Comment: There is always a risk of compromised access token. With shorter expiry that risk is mitigated (e.g. if somebody gets yesterday's token from some log). Now you might say that you can have access token with expiry five hours or another one that expires after five minutes, but you accept it for five hours. It is true that there is no difference in vulnerability, but you are not following standard.